# Are Zerg fully biological beings?

Tags: starcraft

Are the Zerg fully biological beings or are they [bio-technological](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Bio-Technology) as described here, like the Protoss who are half machine and half Protoss?

Comment: If you played the game, it answers itself. They are primitive biological beings that evolve when consuming lesser/higher predators. They can only infect biological beings (corrupt marines). Abathur, an evolution master is creating strains of Zerg using their DNA.

Comment: If the Protoss are half machine and half Protoss, that means that they actually are half machine/quarter machine/quarter Protoss? Which in turns means they are half machine/quarter machine/a eigth machine/a eight Protoss, and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**About Zergs:**

The Zerg have similarities with the Tyranids of Warhammer 40k, these are organic organisms themselves, but can be defined as biotechnological since biotechnology are defined with this:

> Biotechnology is the use of living systems and organisms to develop or make products, or "any technological application that uses biological systems, living organisms, or derivatives thereof, to make or modify products or processes for specific use"

The zergs use other species to improve their "swarm", this process is carried out through modifications of their DNA in their larvae, this generates the different "species" or forms of Zergs that exist. Therefore we can define that if they are users of biotechnology and can apply it in their own bodies.

Another very different thing is what is said in one of the comments about the "infection", since the processes are completely different and have no relation whatsoever.

---

**About Protoss:**

Protoss are not "half machine", they are simply a race with very advanced technology, in addition to having certain psionic abilities. But in no case are they a half-breed robot or something, use armor and weapons just like the Terrans use them, but they are not half machines.

Comment: Protoss Zealots and other warriors have cybernetic implants and Dragoons / Immortals / Stalkers are Protoss warriors melded with machines, so to call some of them "half-machine" isn't entirely incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps, but the immortals and the dragoons really are exoskeletons and about the stalkers i don't think they contain "organic matter" if not rather something like a soul. If I do not go wrong of course ...

Comment: Have you seen the portrait for a Stalker? It's literally a Dark Templar's head on a great big metal body. Granted, it's not "half", but it's still part Biological, part Machine.

Comment: "the stalker is controlled by the shadow-essence of a Dark Templar warrior fused into a metal body." From the portrait... This is not seems a biological Dark templar, essence is more like a soul.

Answer (score 2):

The Zerg are biological by nature. They do have the ability to control alien technology by infesting [buildings](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Infested_terran_buildings) and beings (such as [infested Terrans](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Infested_terran) and [Alexei Stukov](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Alexei_Stukov_(Co-op_Missions)), who controls many different "bio-technological" infestations), resulting in biological machinery, so to speak.

The Protoss utilize [cybernetic implants](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/zealot) to enhance their psionic abilities (and to teleport away when nearing death), so in a way you're right in that they're half machine and half Protoss.

Comment: Protoss **militaries** use cybernetic implants to enhance their ability and/or to compensate for injuries (Dragoons). That makes sense for a technologically advanced race. Us earthlings are already developing exoskeletons for militaries and people with disability. AFAIK, Protoss like Artanis and Zeratul have no implant.